# Eclipse "Permission denied" error when trying to launch app

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to get started creating some apps for Android but I keep running into this Eclipse error:

> NAND: could not read
>   file...android-sdk_r07-windows\android-sdk-windows/platforms\android-7\images/system.img,
>   Permission denied.

Do you think I should delete the package and re-install? I'm wondering whether it could be a corrupted file, although it says "permission denied" which makes me think not so. I just installed the plugin for Eclipse and created my emulator but I can't run because of this error.

I have googled searched this and could not find a relevant answer. Any help would be *greatly* appreciated. :)

Comment: What platform? How did you create the emulator?

Comment: android-sdk_r07? Are you using an antique version of the SDK? How did you set this up?

Comment: I used build target "Android 2.1 - API Level 7" platform 2.1 update 1 when creating a new virtual device in the Android SDK and AVD Manager. I used 1024MiB size for SD card.

Comment: I just downloaded the SDK tonight, so I certainly hope I'm not using an antique version. I set everything up based on how the android developers site recommends for installing the Eclipse plugin. I already created the virtual device and the debug and run configurations using eclipse. Now I'm just trying to launch the application using the emulator.

Comment: I really appreciate the responses. Thanks.Any other information I can provide, I will be more than willing.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like file locking in windows. I will download unlocker for windows and check for processes that have lock on the folder you mentioned. What happens when you run emulator in the command line?

Answer (score 1):

The file seems to be locked or otherwise could not be read.

First you could try to run Eclipse as an Administrator (especially if you are running Windows 7, which has stricter file access than XP).

May I suggest that you download Process Explorer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653 and hit Control-F to search for system.img. Then you'll probably find which process is locking up your file. You can kill the handle in the bottom view of process explorer.

If all else fails you can reinstall Eclipse and/or ADT from scratch. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to log in as a administrator if you are using Windows 7. When you open Eclipse, right-click on the Eclipse icon and select Run as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading developer.android.com - the section about SDK, ADT is not so big. And then maybe reinstalling the SDK step by step.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on the [Android Developers Site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) is very helpful. It couldn't hurt to uninstall the SDK and then try a reinstall closely following the directions given on the above link.

Answer (score 0):

dude you should get the latest sdk version.
also you can try checking if your user has full permissions on the sdk fodler as well as eclipse workspace

Answer (score -1):

has same problem. Solved when i changed target from Android to Google API
[image]
[image]